Project Curve on Mesh - Geometry Nodes
I'm using geometry nodes to project an open curve on a mesh that is not flat. I have used raycast node but can't project the curve along normals (like a polygonal object). I have tried connecting the normal input node in the raycast direction. that doesn't work. What can be done in this scenario?


pls provide your blend file, so that we can tell you how to do it. thx.

Do you mean the normal to the curve, or to the surface ? Because the Raycast node is expecting the normal to the source... In this case, may I recommend to read this post: Raycast Node: Use target normals as rays instead of source normals (replicate Shrinkwrap Target Normal Project mode) ?

maybe you just want to project down?

@StefLAncien, thanks for the reference. I have found a workaround, but it seems your reference is the answer I was looking for. I'll update you about the topic after I find a feasible solution.
